# How to make sure that (input) class properties are not undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

When I work with Angular and TypeScript, I try to write my code as precise and strict as possible. Reviewing some older code, I came across snippets like this:

```
export class UserComponent {

    @Input() user: User;

    getName(): string {
        return this.user.firstname + " " + this.user.lastname;
    }

}
```

Somewhere, this component is used as follows:

```
<user-component [user]="u"></user-component>
```

Obviously, such component is meant to display a user and the whole GUI depends on the user instance (value).

The compiler does not complain about this definition, even though the property `user` could be undefined. However, if another developer forgets to pass the input property `user` to this component, there will be an error in runtime: `Trying to access firstname of undefined`.

How do you work around this problem? Personally, I would prefer if the compiler threw an error if a property was not defined in the custructor. Or is there a way to "force" an input property, so that the compiler/Angular CLI will fail if it is not given when the component is used?

Until now, I only see the following options:

1) Define the user property as `@Input() user: User | undefined`. Then, we have to write a cumbersome if/else in every method that uses the user property.

2) Define `@Input() user: User = new User()`. But then, I still have to check somehow if we have a valid user instance in many uses.

Comment: Have you turned on `strict` option in `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: do you accept any runtime checks that doesn't work during compilation but will fail your component when used without [user] input on runtime?

Comment: Hello @WongJiaHau, I actually did not know about this option. I only have strictNullChecks=true.

Comment: You may find one possible answer [here](https://netbasal.com/how-to-add-angular-component-input-validation-b078a30af97f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick that could work for you is to define component with all of its required fields in selector. In your case it would be

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-component[user][anotherRequiredField]'
})
```

Comment: Does this prevent the developer from using the component without the properties? I didn't know this! If this works, that's great!

Comment: Indeed, the compiler says that the selector is unknown. The error message is a bit weird, but it is there. It says: `error NG8002: Can't bind to 'optionalProperty' since it isn't a known property of 'user-component'`. I skipped the `user` property and the error message says that the optional property isn't a known property.

Comment: it is made for other purposes so Idk if there is a way to make it better. it just won't allow to use the component without required props, I think it is impossible to improve the error message without brute interfering inside of angular logic

Comment: I will accept your answer because it answers the question best. However, I liked to learn about `strict` mode which will also help solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the safe navigation operatore in the template. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

`{{user?.firstname}}` will not throw an error.

If you need to check the input, you could use a setter.

```
@Input() set user(user: User) {
  if (user) ...
```

Comment: Of course, in the template we have the "nice" syntax with `{{ user?.firstname }}`. In the component (class), we still have to check for the user value at every use. The definition of the setter is clear. However, by using strict mode, this would not be necessary?

Comment: strict mode will throw an error, not prevent it. And it will enforce types at compile time with typescript. The data that shows up in the input (or not) at runtime needs to be handled, and error conditions checked.